# Different return type depending on input

Tags: typescript

I have a small challenge with generics, can anybody help?

We have a common websocket connection where different panels in our app "subscribe" to different types of data through socket messages.
`methodCall` below is a common method which sends a "subscribe" message through our open websocket connection and gives parameters for either one type of data or another. The two types have two very different set of properties.

I want to make the following work:

```js
service.methodCall({type: 'oneType'}).subscribe((values: Type1Value) => { ... });
service.methodCall({type: 'anotherType'}).subscribe((values: Type2Value) => { ... });
```

One method returning one specific set of Observable type depending on the given parameter. What needs to to happen in the `methodCall` descriptor to make this happen? The following only gives me union types, which is not what I need:

```js
methodCall(cfg: {type: 'oneType' | 'anotherType'}): Observable<Type1Value | Type2Value> {
  ...
}
```

It's relatively important that the `cfg` object which is input to `methodCall` remains an object and is not flattened out as arguments.

I do not want to create two methods to do this, as this would result in a lot of duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to achieve what you want, assuming that one type will always return an `Observable` of another specific type:

```
methodCall(cfg: { type: 'oneType' }): Observable<Type1Value>
methodCall(cfg: { type: 'anotherType' }): Observable<Type2Value>
methodCall(cfg: { type: 'oneType' | 'anotherType' }): Observable<Type1Value | Type2Value> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: And will this work when `cfg` contains lots of properties?

Comment: It depends: showing a proof-of-concept example in TypeScript playground, for example, will help immensely.